# Helm pre-install yaml for config

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I’ve dependency in `priority class` inside my `k8s` yaml configs files and I need to install **before** any of my yaml inside the template folder
the prio class

```
apiVersion: scheduling.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: PriorityClass
metadata:
  name: ocritical
value: 1000
globalDefault: false
```

After reading the helm docs it seems that I can use the [pre-install hook](http://%20https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/#writing-a-hook)

I’ve changed my yaml and add anotiations section with pre-hook, and still it doesnt works, any idea what I miss here?

```
apiVersion: scheduling.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: PriorityClass
metadata:
  name: ocritical
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install
value: 1000
globalDefault: false
```

The yaml is located inisde the `template` folder

Comment: Helm hook `pre-install` should work. I'm interested in what info you got shows it doesn't work. btw, priorityclass is in stable k8s API since k8s v1.14, (the APIVersion of priorityclass is `scheduling.k8s.io/v1`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put quotation marks for `helm.sh/hook` annotation which is incorrect - you can only add quotation marks for values of them.
You can add description field in your configuration file, remember that this field is an arbitrary string. It is meant to tell users of the cluster when they should use this PriorityClass.

Your PriorityClass should looks like this:

```
apiVersion: scheduling.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: PriorityClass
metadata:
  name: ocritical
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade
    helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: before-hook-creation
value: 1000
globalDefault: false
description: "This priority class should be used for XYZ service pods only."
```

More information about proper configuration of PriorityClass you can find here: [PriorityClass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/).
More information about installing hooks you can find here: [helm-hooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks but now sure where I put a question mark :) , in helm docs the example is  https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/ like `"helm.sh/hook”` and not `helm.sh/hook` , this is the only chanage that I notice in your answer, do I miss someting ?

Comment: Yes, other differences are: I have added additional annotation - helm.sh/hook-delete-policy. I have also added, pre-upgrade ability. Another change is description field in specification of priorityclass.